# Setting a property using reflection which may not be present

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

When trying to set a property added in .Net 4.5 on a system which only has .Net 4.0 you get `MissingMemberException` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.missingmemberexception(v=vs.110).aspx). However you can only catch this when using reflection, otherwise it is an uncatchable JIT exception. ([Why is it not possible to catch MissingMethodException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546580/why-is-it-not-possible-to-catch-missingmethodexception))

So I changed my code from:

```
client.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International;
```

to

```
var p = client.GetType().GetProperty("DeliveryFormat");
if(p!=null)
p.SetValue(client, SmtpDeliveryFormat.International);
```

However now I get a `TypeLoadException` thrown instead about `SmtpDeliveryFormat` because this enum was only added in 4.5 also.

How can I work around this second issue?

Comment: Just curious, is it even possible to run a 4.5 app on a system without the required framework? or you mean you're dynamically loading libraries from older versions?

Comment: Why cant you check for the existence of the property before settings its value?

Comment: Also, the TypeLoadException tells you which type cannot be loaded?

Comment: @thehennyy I suspect the problem is not because the set but the GetType, it will try to load the "Type" class from the V4.5 framework and it doesn't exists as the framework is not installed.

Comment: If the code really runs, you can check "Environment.Version" to retrieve the framework version and then do or don't do the calls to the property.

Comment: Surprisingly it runs just fine - I expected otherwise myself. I just realised the issue is `SmtpDeliveryFormat` doesn't exist in 4.5 either; this is the type the exception is telling me about. I'll update the question...

Comment: @Gusman I didn't realise checking the .Net version was as easy as that. CAn I rely on JIT not to try compiling my code if it's not used?

Comment: No, it will be compiled, but if the function where the code is allocated is not executed it should not rise any exception, so creating two functions, one for 4.5 and other for 4.0 and then only call the correct one should give no problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to go with reflection all the way:

```
var prop = client.GetType().GetProperty("DeliveryFormat");
if (prop != null) {
    var enumType = typeof (SmtpClient).Assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryFormat");
    prop.SetValue(client, Enum.Parse(enumType, "International", null));                                
}
```

This should not throw missing method or type load exceptions in your case.

Comment: You're going to love this, but that overload of `PropertyInfo.SetValue` doesn't exist in 4.0 either! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Mr.Boy well then use one that exists :) prop.SetValue(client, Enum.Parse(enumType, "International", null));

Comment: Yeah I was just testing that before posting :)